# Cancel kotlin flow collection on signal

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm struggling to create a 'takeUntilSignal' operator for a Flow - an extension method that will cancel a flow when another flow generates an output.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilSignal(signal: Flow<Unit>): Flow<T>
```

My initial effort was to try to launch collection of the signal flow in the same coroutine scope as the primary flow collection, and cancel the coroutine scope:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilSignal(signal: Flow<Unit>): Flow<T> = flow {
    kotlinx.coroutines.withContext(coroutineContext) {
        launch {
            signal.take(1).collect()
            println("signalled")
            cancel()
        }
        collect {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
}
```

But this isn't working (and uses the forbidden "withContext" method that is expressly stubbed out by Flow to prevent usage).

*edit*
I've kludged together the following abomination, which doesn't quite fit the definition (resulting flow will only cancel after first emission from primary flow), and I get the feeling there's a far better way out there:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilSignal(signal: Flow<Unit>): Flow<T> =
    combine(
        signal.map { it as Any? }.onStart { emit(null) }
    ) { x, y -> x to y }
        .takeWhile { it.second == null }
        .map { it.first }
```

*edit2*
another try, using channelFlow:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilSignal(signal: Flow<Unit>): Flow<T> =
    channelFlow {
        launch {
            signal.take(1).collect()
            println("hello!")
            close()
        }
        collect { send(it) }
        close()
    }
```

Comment: Why does the signal have to be a Flow? If it was a Deferred (a natural choice for the single-element case), you'd have the `isCompleted` flag to check in each iteration of `collect`.

Comment: Hi Marko - that's an interesting idea! My specific use case is that I have a dialog box  - fields in the dialog box bind to flows, and I want to cancel these flows when the dialog box closes. These flows won't emit when the dialog box closes, leaving these collections in a kind of limbo state.
I can store the jobs for each collect and cancel all of them when the closed signal is received, but that's a lot of book-keeping.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I didn't imply an `async` job but a plain `CompletableDeferred` which you explicitly complete with a value. Closing the dialog box would complete it and all the field-flows would check it and close themselves when it completes.

Comment: Hi Marko - if I undertand right it would be something like
collect { if (signal.isCompleted) throw CancellationException() else emit(it) }

Comment: Yes, for example `first()` works the same way, by throwing an exception: `try {
        collect { value ->
            result = value;
            throw AbortFlowException()
        }
    } catch (e: AbortFlowException) {
        // Do nothing
    }
`

Comment: I do see a problem with my suggestion, the `collect` block isn't invoked until there's another item to collect. So it will still hang.

Comment: yes I think that was my initial concern - because of the nature of the dialog box, the collect block won't be invoked again after the dialog is closed, so the coroutine will hang.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `couroutineScope` and start the new coroutine inside:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.takeUntilSignal(signal: Flow<Unit>): Flow<T> = flow {
    try {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
                signal.take(1).collect()
                println("signalled")
                this@coroutineScope.cancel()
            }

            collect {
                emit(it)
            }
        }

    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        //ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? A small test does work. And it is a child scope of the original scope. Could you point me to the description, which scope is allowed. Thank you.

Comment: I found here https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/ that it is allowed to emit in an inner coroutineScope.

Comment: `coroutineScope { }` is equivalent to `withContext(coroutineScope) { }` and, while the latter is formally forbidden, it's only because you could use any context. So this should work.

Comment: This doesn't compile: `not enough information to infer type variable R`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky There is no variable R in this code example. Could you provide your code?

Comment: Just an FYI `take(1).collect()` can be shortened to `first()`.

Answer (score 3):

Check it https://github.com/hoc081098/FlowExt

```kotlin
package com.hoc081098.flowext

import com.hoc081098.flowext.internal.ClosedException
import com.hoc081098.flowext.internal.checkOwnership
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.take
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

/**
 * Emits the values emitted by the source [Flow] until a [notifier] [Flow] emits a value or completes.
 *
 * @param notifier The [Flow] whose first emitted value or complete event
 * will cause the output [Flow] of [takeUntil] to stop emitting values from the source [Flow].
 */
public fun <T, R> Flow<T>.takeUntil(notifier: Flow<R>): Flow<T> = flow {
  try {
    coroutineScope {
      val job = launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
        notifier.take(1).collect()
        throw ClosedException(this@flow)
      }

      collect { emit(it) }
      job.cancel()
    }
  } catch (e: ClosedException) {
    e.checkOwnership(this@flow)
  }
}
```