# How to Unsubscribe from coroutine flows right after RoomDb call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to query Room database(action 1) and then based on the returned results perform another action on the same table. however I noticed that every time I perform the second action, coroutine will query the database(action 1). but this is not I want. just as an example:

My ItemDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
fun selectItems():Flow<List<Item>>

@Insert
suspend fun insertItem(item:Item)
```

for example I want to perform `selectItems()` first and if the list is empty immediately call `insertItem(item)`

```
fun insertIfListEmpty(item:Item){

    val job=CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        itemDao.selectItems().collect{
          log.d(TAG,"items collected")
          if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
             itemDao.insertItem(item)
          }
        }

    }

}
```

but after `itemDao.insertItem(item)` it shows log message again.even if I call `itemDao.insertItem(item)` from another method again it shows log message. is there any way to unsubscribe the coroutine right after collect?

Comment: You can cancel the CoroutineScope flow is in. `this@launch.cancel()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel kotlin flow collection on signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102397/cancel-kotlin-flow-collection-on-signal)

Comment: I don't know how to use that code

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional method in the `ItemDao`, which will return the number of elements, and then check if it equals to 0 then insert data.

ItemDao:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_table")
suspend fun getItemCount(): Int
```

Function:

```
fun insertIfListEmpty(item: Item) {
    someCoroutineScope.launch {
        if (itemDao.getItemCount() == 0) {
             itemDao.insertItem(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the collect body, you can throw a cancellation exception

```
yourFlow.collect {
    throw kotlinx.coroutines.CancellationException()
    }
```